# Create custom Wordpress post type with template selector (Page UI)?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know how to create custom post types.  It seems from looking at the Codex that I should be able to create a custom post type that behaves like a page, specifically the ability to assign a template with the template chooser pop-up and category/tag pickers.

So far all I get is the basic editor, and I can get a featured image selector.  But what I am looking for is basically a Page that I can treat as a custom post type.

EDIT:  I thought it would be obvious, but I was doing it with functions.php:

```
register_post_type( hh_town,
array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Towns' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Town' ),
        'add_new' => _x('Add Town', 'towns'),
              'add_new_item' => __('Add Town'),
              'edit' => _x('Edit Towns', 'Towns'),
              'edit_item' => __('Edit Town'),
              'new_item' => __('New Town'),
              'view' => _x('View Town', 'towns'),
              'view_item' => __('View Town')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','page-attributes','thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','category')
)
);
```

Comment: Ok, but how are you doing that? Plugin or custom code? Please provide links, screenshots and/or sample code.

Comment: I edited my question to include the code I am using.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this code to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_page_attributes_meta_box' );
function add_custom_page_attributes_meta_box(){
global $post;
    if ( 'page' != $post->post_type && post_type_supports($post->post_type, 'page-attributes') ) {
        add_meta_box( 'custompageparentdiv', __('Template'), 'custom_page_attributes_meta_box', NULL, 'side', 'core');
    }
}

function custom_page_attributes_meta_box($post) {
    $template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', 1 ); ?>
    <select name="page_template" id="page_template">
        <?php $default_title = apply_filters( 'default_page_template_title',  __( 'Default Template' ), 'meta-box' ); ?>
        <option value="default"><?php echo esc_html( $default_title ); ?></option>
        <?php page_template_dropdown($template); ?>
    </select><?php
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_page_attributes_meta_box' );
function save_custom_page_attributes_meta_box( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) return;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['page_template'] ) && get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'page' ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', $_POST['page_template'] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but in case someone comes across this: you don't actually need any custom meta boxes any more. If you create a template like
`template-my-template.php` and add this to the top

```php
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Template
Template Post Type: project, report, event
*/
```

Then any custom post type listed in `Template Post Type` which also supports page-attributes (`add_post_type_support( 'my_post_type', ['page-attributes'] );`) will allow template selection.